# SQL Server inline view bug?

Tags: sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 2012 and having what I think is a very strange issue with inline views.

To begin with, I have this query:

```
select 
    parcelnumber, 
    sectionname,
    value.Value CalculatedValue,
    overriddenvalue.Value OverriddenValue,
    homk.Value CalculatedHomeownersValue,
    cv.CharacteristicValue,
    pdt.PropertyDataTypeID
from landsections ls
join lands l 
  on ls.landid = ls.landid
join parcels p
  on l.ParcelID = p.ParcelID
join CharacteristicValueGroups cvg
  on cvg.ParcelObjectID = ls.ParcelObjectID
join CharacteristicValues cv 
  on cvg.CharacteristicValueGroupID = cv.CharacteristicValueGroupID
join Characteristics c
  on cv.CharacteristicID = c.CharacteristicID
join CharacteristicDetails cd
  on c.CharacteristicDetailsID = cd.CharacteristicDetailsID
 and cd.name = '09 Composite Adjustment'
join PropertyDataTypes pdt
  on cv.PropertyDataTypeID = pdt.PropertyDataTypeID
 and pdt.Label = 'Type'
join parcelobjectvalues value
  on value.ParcelObjectID = ls.ParcelObjectID
 and value.valuetype = 'CalculatedAdjustedValue'
left join parcelobjectvalues overriddenvalue
  on overriddenvalue.ParcelObjectID = ls.ParcelObjectID
 and overriddenvalue.valuetype = 'OverriddenValue'
join parcelobjectvalues homk
  on homk.ParcelObjectID = ls.ParcelObjectID
 and homk.valuetype = 'CalculatedHomeownersValue'
where year(appraisaldate) = 2016
  and CharacteristicValue like '%F%'
```

Note the last item in the where clause. This query return 0 results, which should prove that there are no rows that have a `CharacteristicValue` column containing an F.

Now lets run this query:

```
select *
from
(
    select 
        *,
        case 
            when CharacteristicValue like '%A' then convert(int, substring(characteristicvalue, 1, len(characteristicvalue) - 1))
            when CharacteristicValue like '%K' then convert(int, substring(characteristicvalue, 1, len(characteristicvalue) - 1))
            when isnumeric(CharacteristicValue) = 1 then convert(int, characteristicvalue)
            else 0
        end Quantity
    from
    (
        select 
            parcelnumber, 
            sectionname,
            value.Value CalculatedValue,
            overriddenvalue.Value OverriddenValue,
            homk.Value CalculatedHomeownersValue,
            cv.CharacteristicValue,
            pdt.PropertyDataTypeID
        from
            landsections ls
            join lands l on ls.landid = ls.landid
            join parcels p on l.ParcelID = p.ParcelID
            join CharacteristicValueGroups cvg on cvg.ParcelObjectID = ls.ParcelObjectID
            join CharacteristicValues cv on cvg.CharacteristicValueGroupID = cv.CharacteristicValueGroupID
            join Characteristics c on cv.CharacteristicID = c.CharacteristicID
            join CharacteristicDetails cd on c.CharacteristicDetailsID = cd.CharacteristicDetailsID and cd.name = '09 Composite Adjustment'
            join PropertyDataTypes pdt on cv.PropertyDataTypeID = pdt.PropertyDataTypeID and pdt.Label = 'Type'
            join parcelobjectvalues value on value.ParcelObjectID = ls.ParcelObjectID and value.valuetype = 'CalculatedAdjustedValue'
            left join parcelobjectvalues overriddenvalue on overriddenvalue.ParcelObjectID = ls.ParcelObjectID and overriddenvalue.valuetype = 'OverriddenValue'
            join parcelobjectvalues homk on homk.ParcelObjectID = ls.ParcelObjectID and homk.valuetype = 'CalculatedHomeownersValue'
        where
            year(appraisaldate) = 2016
    ) Tbl
) Tbl2
where
    CharacteristicValue like '%A' and Quantity > 10
```

Notice that I've removed the %F% check. Since the first query proved there were no rows with an F in the `CharacteristicValue` column, I would assume the outer query could rely on this.

However, I get this:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'F' to data type int.

I think the only way this could happen is ignoring the `pdt.Label = 'Type'`, but for the life of me I can't understand why.

Comment: If you add the %F% filter to the second query, does it not return the same error?

Comment: `CharacteristicValue` is this an `INT` data type column ???

Comment: Try just  "select * from CharacteristicValues where CharacteristicValue like '%F%'" and see if that returns anything.

Comment: Adding the F filter back in gives me the same error. Which really I don't think should happen because it's returning 0 rows. If I do a not like '%F%', then I get a similar error about an 'O'. Both 'F' and 'O' characters should not show up in this column at all due to the pdt.Label = 'Type' and cd.name = '09 Composite Adjustment'

Comment: CharacteristicValue is a varchar

Comment: `isnumeric()` is a poor choice of function to check if it is really a numeric value since it will return true for values like `123e12` or `456d1`, you should use LIKE operator something like `WHERE CharacteristicValue NOT LIKE '[^0-9]'`

Comment: The select * from CharacteristicValues where CharacteristicValue like '%F%' would return many rows because there are ones with an F in them. But these should be filtered out by the pdt.Label and cd.Name filters

Comment: I think isnumeric should be fine in this case. The values I'm expecting are going to be either an integer or an integer followed by an A or a K.

Comment: You have a lot of joins with multiple tables, you said you have data with '%F%' in table and pdt.Lavel and cd.Name will filter them out. I am not sure about this because you join through another table.

Comment: I would have thought that the results from "Tbl" would have been determined first and then "Tbl2" would query off of those results, but are you saying that's not the case?

Comment: I think you're on to something. I did a check for pdt.Label and cd.Name in the case statement and got it to work. I'm still wondering why the original query doesn't work. I am guessing it's related to allowing correlated subqueries? I say this because that would mean Tbl couldn't have been executed first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your view filters on:

```
where year(appraisaldate) = 2016 and CharacteristicValue like '%F%'
```

Which means that there can be rows that satisfy just `CharacteristicValue like '%F%'`.

Execution order is not specified in T-SQL. This is a problem when trying to guard calculations that might throw with some check.

Usually, `case ... when` is a reliable guard. I see no reason why it wouldn't in your case. So you could do `when CharacteristicValue like '%A' and CharacteristicValue not like '%F%'`.

Or, you can use `TRY_CONVERT` which is always safe.

`where` is *not* a reliable guard. In the other answer you posted that this works but that is just coincidence. With a different query plan this might fail. Plans change for many reasons.

Answer (score -1):

The answer appears to be that the inner query can't be executed prior to the outer query due to correlation. Adding filters in the outer query solved the issue.